# Multiple IF statements in simple form validation

Tags: php

I am a newbie and trying to implement a simple validation script after reading up, but I can't see how I can have multiple Ifs that will only do an sql insert if all required fields are met. Rather than having the multiple else statements, what is a syntax approach for having all the form validation Ifs together and if one of them fails, then the correct error is shown and  the sql is not execute?

```
if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

$catErr = $ratingErr = $titleErr = $textErr = "";

if (empty($_POST["category"])) {
$catErr = "Category is required";
} else {
//DO THE INSERT BELOW!
}

if (empty($_POST["rating"])) {
$ratingErr = "Rating is required";
} else {
//DO THE INSERT BELOW!
}

if (empty($_POST["post_name"])) {
$postErr = "Title is required";
} else {
//DO THE INSERT BELOW!
}

if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
$textErr = "Text is required";
} else {
//DO THE INSERT BELOW!
}


//PDO query begins here...

$sql = "INSERT INTO forum(ID,
category,
rating,
post_name,
text
```

Comment: One method is to set a flag on error (`$errors=true`) and then only execute your SQL if, for example, `$errors==false`.

Comment: That would not allow him to echo the desired error statment.

Comment: @Theyouthis I'm not suggesting that the OP get rid of the specific error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one variable for all the error messages and concatenate to it in the branches, so in the end if that variable is still empty string you won't do the insert. (And you don't need any of the empty else blocks that contain nothing but a comment.)

```
$err = "";

if (empty($_POST["category"])) {
$err .= "<br/>Category is required";
} 

if (empty($_POST["rating"])) {
$err .= "<br/>Rating is required";
} 

if (empty($_POST["post_name"])) {
$err .= "<br/>Title is required";
} 

if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
$err .= "<br/>Text is required";
}

//PDO query begins here...
if($err=='')
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO forum(ID,
category,
rating,
...";
...
}
```

Comment: I like that, but then what goes in each of the else statements? I don't want to include all those parameter binds 4 times for each variable. Or did you mean I leave the else statements blank just as you have it above?

Comment: Just exactly like I have it above will work. You don't need the `else` blocks when you aren't actually going to do anything in them.

Comment: This works... but is very ugly. You should remove brackets to save on lines. Also, why use double quotes when you declare the `$err` variable but use single quotes when you check for it's emptiness?

Comment: Removing brackets to save on lines sounds silly to me since you lose readability. Its not like line numbers is a bad thing when its readable. (In fact, personally I'd put the opening bracket on a newline and indent the inside with a tab to make it more readable.) I just left the double quotes the OP had in the declaration, but normally for empty string I'd use single, so that's why.

Comment: @ developerwjk This works well (I just had to add an echo $errs before the //PDO comment line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**There are many solutions to your problem. Here are 3 methods of solving your issue.**

You could combine all of your if statements like so:

```
if (empty($_POST['rating']) || empty($_POST'rating']) || ... ) { ... }
```

and separate them by double pipes.

You could also check the entire array:

```
if (empty($_POST)) $error = "There was an error!";
```

You could set a universal error variable and then output it.

A third solution could keep your current syntax but cut down on the amount of lines. You could save lines by doing without brackets. You can create an array and push your errors to the array.

***Note:*** You can use `empty()` or `isset()`.

```
// create an array to push errors to
$errors_array = array();

// if a particular field is empty then push the relevant error to the array
if(!isset($_POST['category'])) array_push($errors_array, "Category is required");
if(!isset($_POST['rating'])) array_push($errors_array, "Rating is required");
...
```

Once you have an array full of errors you can check for them like so:

```
// if the array is not empty (then there are errors! don't insert!)
if (count($errors_array) > 0) {
    // loop through and echo out the errors to the page
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($errors_array); $i++) {
        echo $errors_array[i];
    }
} else {
    // success! run your query!
}
```

Comment: I am looking into implementing the third solution. Shouldn't it be if(!isset) as in NOT set for each variable then display error code? And then I would just put the query in an else statement at the end of all these if statements (which would also be bracketed?)

Comment: Yes, you are right! Editing my post. However, you can still use `empty()` if you want. And yes, you may put your query where it says `// success! insert your data!`.

Comment: There is no need to have an else for the `isset()` if statements. If you do that you need to include brackets for all the previous statements. This will increase the amount of lines and is unnecessary since it is being handled in the `count()` if statement.

Comment: I like the approach but so far when I hit submit the form just submits and adds a row to the database with all blank values, so for some reason, the validation isn't kicking in...

Comment: You will have to do a little debugging. You may need to slightly change my code. If you understand my approach you should be able to debug up to the point where it stops working. I will comment my code to better explain what is going on.

Comment: You should do things like echo out `count($errors_array);` and see if the array has a length when fields are empty/not empty. Then echo out your field variables inside your `else` and see if they are empty. Are you sure you are inserting your variables into your query correctly?

Comment: Yes, the query worked fine until I tried the validation stuff. Could it be because I removed the if(isset($_POST ['submit'])) at the top of my code when I tried your approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59535/discussion-between-nicolas-and-jaw).

Comment: I made a syntax error, which is why it isn't working correctly. Come to chat to see the working code.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this! While I was waiting, I implemented a different approach successfully as you can see below. However, yours might be better for showing errors right on page and keeping form. I am going to hold off on chat for a bit because I have to step out for a few minutes....

Comment: Well once you come back in check out this: http://pastebin.com/1H1wJEBx It is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks. Send chat...same issue...form just sends regardless if fields are blank.

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to validate the page before it is even processed into a post. This script will run client-side when they hit submit and catch errors before they even leave the page.

Here's a tutorial on how to do something like that: [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)

Each field can have its own validation parameters and methods, and it will also make the page's code look a lot nicer.

Comment: What if the user has javascript disabled? They would be able to by-pass any validation on the client side.  A nefarious user could also construct their own form that will just post directly to your server script with no validation whatsoever. Client side validation is _not_ a replacement for server side validation.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to go with this approach after showdev got me thinking that way. It's not very elegant perhaps, but does the trick, although all the user is taken to a blank page if there are errors and it simple says: Missing category (or whatever). Wondering if I can echo a link or something back to the page with the form from there so the user has an option like "go back and resubmit". Otherwise I will have to handle and display the errors alongside the form which will require a different approach altogether...

```
if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){

$errors = false;
if(empty($_POST['category'])) {
echo 'Missing category.<br>';
$errors = true;
}

if(empty($_POST['rating'])) {
echo 'Missing rating.<br>';
$errors = true;
}

if(empty($_POST['post_name'])) {
echo 'Missing title.<br>';
$errors = true;
}

if(empty($_POST['text'])) {
echo 'Missing text.<br>';
$errors = true;
}

if($errors) {
exit;
}
```

// THEN ADD CODE HERE. But how display form again if user makes errors and sees nothing but error message on page if they miss something (which is how it works now)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you find yourself repeatedly writing very similar statements, using some sort of loop is probably a better way to go about it. I think what you said about "handling and displaying the errors alongside the form" is really what you need to do if you want the process to be user-friendly. If you put your validation script at the top of the file that has your form in it, then you can just have the form submit to itself (`action=""`). If the submission is successful, you can redirect the user elsewhere, and if not, they will see the form again, with error messages in useful places.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // define your required fields and create an array to hold errors
    $required = array('category', 'rating', 'post_name', 'text');
    $errors = array();
    // loop over the required fields array and verify their non-emptiness
    foreach ($required as $field) {
        // Use empty rather than isset here. isset only checks that the 
        // variable exists and is not null, so blank entries can pass.
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $errors[$field] = "$field is required";
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        // insert the record; redirect to a success page (or wherever)
    }
}

// Display the form, showing errors from the $errors array next to the
// corresponding inputs
```

Comment: I get an error about an unexpected { for the line: if (empty($_POST[$field]) {

Comment: @jaw, Sorry about that, I missed a closing paren.